# ACS PUMS Data Dictionary Codes in .csv?

Tags: usa, us-census

I found me [some data](http://www2.census.gov/acs2013_3yr/pums/), and I'd like to be able to filter, and aggregate the responses in a relational database. However it seems the [Data dictionaries](http://www.census.gov/acs/www/data_documentation/pums_documentation/) are either in xls (but not a format easily transformed into csv, or in pdf, or in txt with a similar style to the pdf.

Comment: those zip files contain a pdf and a csv

Comment: @albert - the CSV is the data and not the data dictionary the OP is looking for

Comment: Have you seen the "PUMS Data Dictionary" section in the bottom left of http://www.census.gov/acs/www/data_documentation/pums_documentation/ ? There is a .txt file available which is probably your best bet for writing a parser against. Those .txt files appear to have the same content as the PDF/XLS files you are referencing which are found under "Code Lists"

Comment: @Skram - I forgot to mention the txt files in the Q. I was hoping someone out on the net might have already parsed them.

Comment: my bad for not reading entirely. sorry guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a plethora of XLS converters and scripts out there, but the easiest way IMO is to use google drive in this case. I uploaded the first of the dictionaries, 2011-2013 3-year Code Lists, took about 20 seconds. Now you can edit it in the browser or download as CSV. you can do the same for the text files. check it out - [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MUHvvZbCnRaEYCmVKZxX4cWbo0ghXugqiK7GmyN6YtQ/edit#gid=1900659708)

Comment: if you know python, the xldr package is a very simple way to read Excel files. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd

Comment: yeah thats a good one. seemed like op didn't want technical answer, so i gave the easy one

Comment: After talking to some folks in the lab I'm beginning to feel like I shouldn't be thinking of this data relationally (and PostgreSQL in particular has issues with pivoting). I ended up using `cut` on the columns I wanted and uploaded that + a csv of the coded answers for the question I was interested in.
Thanks @albert!